# Background process (nohup &) suspends/resumes when user logs out/logs in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nohup

Ubuntu Server 11.10

When a normal (non-root) user starts a process with nohup, when the user disconnects from the terminal the process (java) stops responding.  When the user connects again, the process starts responding again.

Is there any background process permissions that I'm not aware of that precludes the process from running in background?
What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Try running it with tmux or screen, and then detaching the tmux or screen session.

Comment: @Rob, thanks but it still doesn't work... and it is not quite what I need.  What I ended up doing is running such processes as root ... which is far from ideal.  When I find the cause I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually redirect `stdout` and `stderr` as well as using `nohup`. I'm not sure if it is necessary but it works for me.

If the program ever reads from `stdin` it will wait.